# Facebook share image with target url

Tags: javascript, facebook, image

i am currently developing a "share on facebook" feature but i don't know if it is possible.
The user should have a share button on a webpage, but with the button he doesn't share the page he shares an image.

When another user sees the image on facebook, and clicks on it, he should get redirected to a url i can choose.

i can't simply share the whole site and use open graph tags because the page where the share button is located is on a private area of the website and can only be accessed when you log in.

this whole thing must be done via javascript on client side.
perfect solution for me would be if i can use sth. like

`FB.ui(...,
   {image: 'path to image', 
    url: 'url to call when image is clicked on fb'},...
 );`

Any ideas?

Comment: You either share a link, or you don’t. You can’t have a normal photo arbitrarily link to just anywhere you want. _“because the page where the share button is located is on a private area of the website and can only be accessed when you log in”_ – it doesn’t matter where the share button is located, it matters what URL you share … so share one that is outside of the private area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a onclick="shareit()">Share on facebook</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function shareit(){
var url="http://www.example.com"; //Set desired URL here
var img="http://www.example.com/example.jpg"; //Set Desired Image here
var totalurl=encodeURIComponent(url+'?img='+img);

window.open ('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+totalurl,'','width=500, height=500, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no');

}
</script>
```

Besides when you pass OG image as querystring to the target URL, in the target URL you will need a code which retrievs the image address and set it as OG image. So in target URL you will need this line:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php $_GET['img'] ?>">
```

Comment: not the solution i am looking for, since this only shares a site and displays the image (because of og:image) along with some other information. What i need is only the image in facebook preview (like you only pass the url to the image) but when you click the image on fb you don't get redirected to the image but an url instead.

Comment: i can't figure out a solution to my problem. Ali Sheikhpours solution is the closest i can get when i use a large image face shows it on top of the shared link and not to the left of it.

Comment: Facebook automatically decides to display image on top or left on posts according to image size. You can implement resizing image components (like aspJpeg) to resize images on the fly.

Comment: Also there is essential difference between image sharing and link sharing on Facebook and you can not simulate other one by programming on your server. A close way to gain this is to set empty Og title and OG description and so there only remains an image and an automatic gray link to page address.